# Input form value remains the same even with an onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This code is a functional component that should render a user detail page(Show details view) OR a form to edit(Edit detail view) this user info depending on the state of *isUpdate*. This works alright,  as the ***update*** and ***save*** buttons change the state of ***isUpdate*** to render the Edit View or Show View respectively.

When I select a user, the page gets the specific user by ***match.params.id*** which also works. My problem is when the ***isUpdate*** is set to  ***true*** (the edit form with the original values of the user details is rendered)  I expect that the input values change when I type on the input for,   but instead the value remains the same as its original value(unable to type new values).
I dont know why I am facing this problem.

UserDetail Component code below:

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { connect }                            from 'react-redux';
import { findUser }                           from '../../actions/user';

const UserDetails =({match, user, loading, findUser}) => {
    
    const[isUpdate, setIsUpdate]=useState(false);
    
    //fetching user info based on the params id
        useEffect(() => {
    findUser(match.params.id);
    
    },[])
    
    //setting the initial state of user to  the values from the fetched data
    const[userData, setUserData]=useState({
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
    });
    
    //on Change handler
      const onChange = e =>{
          setUserData({...userData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
      }
      
      //User detail rendered to be viewed or edited
    return loading  ? 
        (<Fragment>
            <div className="loader-container" ></div>
                   <div className="loader"></div>  
        </Fragment>) :
    
        (isUpdate ? (
    
         <Fragment> 
            <div className="detail-container">
                
              <form>
                  
                <div className="form-row">  
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name:</label>
                      <input
                          type="name"
                          className="form-control"
                          id="name"
                          name="name"
                          value={user.name}
                          onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                      <input
                          type="email" 
                          className="form-control" 
                          id="email"
                          name="email"
                          value={user.email}
                          onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>setIsUpdate(false)}>SAVE</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </Fragment>):
         (<Fragment>
            <div className="detail-container">
                
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mb-20"> <button className="btn btn-warning "
                        onClick={()=>setIsUpdate(true)}> UPDATE</button>
                </div>
                
                <div className="row mb-10">
                   <div className=" col-md-6">
                        <div className="detail-label">Full Name:</div>
                        <div className="detail">{`${user.name}`}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className=" col-md-6">
                        <div className="detail-label">Email:</div>
                        <div className="detail">{`${user.email}`}</div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</Fragment>))


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user.a_user,
    loading: state.user.loading
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{findUser})(UserDetails);
```

Please I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` data remains constant during the editing session, so the `input` element cannot work properly. Try to change its declaration using the `userData` instead:

```
                  <input
                      type="name"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="name"
                      name="name"
                      value={userData.name}
                      onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
```

UPDATE: in order to update the `userData` state whenever the `user` changes, you could use this trick:

```
const[userData, setUserData]=useState();

useEffect(
    () => {
        setUserData({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
        });
    },
    [user]
);
```

Take care to handle the initial condition where `userData` is undefined.

Comment: I did that earlier, but I encountered a different problem. The problem I encountered: 

The first time  I pick a user(user1), it fetched the user1 detail and then when I click the {update} button, the edit view shows with an empty form. When I go back back to the users list and click a new user (user2), the details view shows, but when I click the update button, the edit form shows with the details of user1. And goes on like this...

I am new to **REACT HOOKS** and not sure about the use here,  but I believe the problem might be from that. 

What do you think about this issue?

Comment: the `useState` hook takes the init value passed in only the very first time is instantiated. If you see the same user after changing the source, it means the component keeps the same, along its state. That being said, instead passing the `user` straight to the hook, consider an `useEffect` observing that, and which updates the state when changes. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your form inputs values should be targetting userData instead of user i.e

```
<input 
    ...name="name"
    value={userData.name} />
```

2. You need to set your userData in the useEffect method as it seems that for each user, the userData value is using values fetched previously.

```
     useEffect(() => {
    findUser(match.params.id)
    setUserData(user)
    },[])
```

I'm guessing the findUser method updates the user in the parent component.
This should work.